# Lazarus: TListBox.Style:= lbVirtual but no OnData event

Tags: listbox, freepascal, lazarus

From Delphi 6 on it was possible to put millions of lines in the `TListBox` component via `.Style:= lbVirtual` and using the `OnData` event. In Lazarus `lbVirtual` exists, too, but not the `OnData` event. I want to extend this component to be able to display millions of lines, but I get errors during compilation.

My problem is that I can't really port code from Delphi to Lazarus when it comes to using `lbVirtual` in Lazarus, as no `OnData` event exists.

- Delphi 7:

  ```
  ListBox.Style:= lbVirtual;
  property OnData;
  ListBox.Count:=  // for reading
  ```
- Lazarus:

  ```
  ListBox.Style:= lbVirtual;  // which behaves like lbStandard
  ListBox.Count:=  // ReadOnly
  ```

In Lazarus I used the `property OnData` in my new `L_Listbox` component and `ListBox.Count:=`. I still don't know if `L_ListBox` lines will show up like I know it from `lbVirtual`. Now I get compiler error messages such as

> resourcestring

> LongInt

I thought I would solve this by appending to `uses Math`. However, it did not help. All compilation errors pop up in the file: **l_listbox.pas**

**LLB.pas**

```
{ This file was automatically created by Lazarus. Do not edit!
  This source is only used to compile and install the package.
 }

unit LLB;

{$warn 5023 off : no warning about unused units}
interface

uses
  L_ListBox, LazarusPackageIntf;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterUnit('L_ListBox', @L_ListBox.Register);
end;

initialization
  RegisterPackage('LLB', @Register);
end.
```

**LLB.lpk**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONFIG>
  <Package Version="4">
    <PathDelim Value="\"/>
    <Name Value="LLB"/>
    <Type Value="RunAndDesignTime"/>
    <CompilerOptions>
      <Version Value="11"/>
      <PathDelim Value="\"/>
      <SearchPaths>
        <UnitOutputDirectory Value="lib\$(TargetCPU)-$(TargetOS)\"/>
      </SearchPaths>
    </CompilerOptions>
    <Files Count="1">
      <Item1>
        <Filename Value="l_listbox.pas"/>
        <HasRegisterProc Value="True"/>
        <UnitName Value="L_ListBox"/>
      </Item1>
    </Files>
    <RequiredPkgs Count="2">
      <Item1>
        <PackageName Value="LCL"/>
      </Item1>
      <Item2>
        <PackageName Value="FCL"/>
      </Item2>
    </RequiredPkgs>
    <UsageOptions>
      <UnitPath Value="$(PkgOutDir)"/>
    </UsageOptions>
    <PublishOptions>
      <Version Value="2"/>
      <UseFileFilters Value="True"/>
    </PublishOptions>
  </Package>
</CONFIG>
```

**l_listbox.pas** (see comments where the compiler complains in `function TListBoxStrings.GetObject(Index: Integer): TObject;`)

```
unit L_ListBox;

  {$mode objfpc}{$H+}
     
  interface

  uses Math, StdCtrls, Controls, Classes, Forms, Graphics, Messages, Windows, SysUtils, Commctrl, Types,
     LResources, LCLType, LCLIntf, LMessages;

  resourcestring
    SErrorSettingCount = 'Error setting %s.Count';
    SListBoxMustBeVirtual = 'Listbox (%s) style must be virtual in order to set Count';
    SListIndexError = 'List %s   is invalid';
     
  type
    TListBoxStyle = (lbStandard, lbOwnerDrawFixed, lbOwnerDrawVariable, lbVirtual, lbVirtualOwnerDraw);

    TLBGetDataEvent       = procedure(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; var Data: string) of object;
    TLBFindDataEvent      = function(Control : TWinControl; FindString: string): Integer of object;
    TLBGetDataObjectEvent = procedure(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; var DataObject: TObject) of object;

  TL_ListBox = class(Tlistbox)

  private
    FCount    : Integer;
    FStyle    : TListBoxStyle;

    FOnDataFind   : TLBFindDataEvent;
    FOnData       : TLBGetDataEvent;
    FOnDataObject : TLBGetDataObjectEvent;

    function GetSelCount : Integer;

    function GetCount : Integer;
    procedure SetCount(const Value: Integer);

    procedure SetStyle(Value: TListBoxStyle);

  protected

    function DoGetData(const Index: Integer): String;
    function DoGetDataObject(const Index: Integer): TObject;
    function DoFindData(const Data: String): Integer;

    function InternalGetItemData(Index: Integer): Longint; dynamic;
    procedure InternalSetItemData(Index: Integer; AData: Longint); dynamic;

    function GetItemData(Index: Integer): LongInt; dynamic;
    procedure SetItemData(Index: Integer; AData: LongInt); dynamic;

    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;

  public

    property SelCount : Integer read GetSelCount;
    property Count : Integer read GetCount write SetCount;

  published

    property OnData       : TLBGetDataEvent read FOnData write FOnData;
    property OnDataObject : TLBGetDataObjectEvent read FOnDataObject write FOnDataObject;
    property OnDataFind   : TLBFindDataEvent read FOnDataFind write FOnDataFind;

    property Style: TListBoxStyle read FStyle write SetStyle default lbStandard;

  end;

  procedure Register;

  implementation

  uses  RTLConsts;

  procedure Register;
  begin
  
   RegisterComponents('ex',[TL_ListBox]);
  end;

  type
    TListBoxStrings = class(TStrings)
      private
        ListBox: TL_ListBox;

      protected

        function GetCount: Integer; override;
        function GetObject(Index: Integer): TObject; override;
        procedure PutObject(Index: Integer; AObject: TObject); override;

      public

  end;
     
  { TL_ListBox }

    procedure TL_ListBox.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
  const
    Styles: array[TListBoxStyle] of DWORD = (0, LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED, LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE, LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED, LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED);

    Data: array[Boolean] of DWORD = (LBS_HASSTRINGS, LBS_NODATA);
  begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
    CreateSubClass(Params, 'ListBox');
    with Params do begin

    Style := Style or ({WS_HSCROLL or }WS_VSCROLL or Data[Self.Style in [lbVirtual]] or LBS_NOTIFY) or Styles[FStyle];
   end;
  end;

  function TL_ListBox.DoFindData(const Data: String): Integer;
  begin
    if Assigned(FOnDataFind) then Result := FOnDataFind(Self, Data) else Result := -1;
  end;
     
  function TL_ListBox.DoGetData(const Index: Integer): String;
  begin
    if Assigned(FOnData) then FOnData(Self, Index, Result);
  end;
     
  function TL_ListBox.DoGetDataObject(const Index: Integer): TObject;
  begin
    if Assigned(FOnDataObject) then FOnDataObject(Self, Index, Result);
  end;

  function TL_ListBox.GetCount: Integer;
  begin
    if Style in [lbVirtual] then Result := FCount else Result := Items.Count;
  end;
     
  function TL_ListBox.GetItemData(Index: Integer): LongInt;
  begin
    Result := SendMessage(Handle, LB_GETITEMDATA, Index, 0);
  end;

  function TL_ListBox.GetSelCount: Integer;
  begin
    Result := SendMessage(Handle, LB_GETSELCOUNT, 0, 0);
  end;

  function TL_ListBox.InternalGetItemData(Index: Integer): Longint;
  begin
    Result := GetItemData(Index);
  end;
     
  procedure TL_ListBox.InternalSetItemData(Index, AData: Integer);
  begin
    SetItemData(Index, AData);
  end;

  procedure TL_ListBox.SetCount(const Value: Integer);
  var
    Error: Integer;
  begin
    if Style in [lbVirtual] then
  begin
    // Limited to 32767 on Win95/98 as per Win32 SDK
    Error := SendMessage(Handle, LB_SETCOUNT, Value, 0);
     if (Error <> LB_ERR) and (Error <> LB_ERRSPACE) then FCount := Value else raise Exception.CreateFmt(LoadStr(SErrorSettingCount), [Name]);
  end
     else raise Exception.CreateFmt(LoadStr(SListBoxMustBeVirtual), [Name]);
  end;

  procedure TL_ListBox.SetItemData(Index, AData: Integer);
  begin
    SendMessage(Handle, LB_SETITEMDATA, Index, AData);
  end;

  procedure TL_ListBox.SetStyle(Value: TListBoxStyle);
  begin
  if FStyle <> Value then
  begin
    if Value in [lbVirtual] then
    begin
      Items.Clear;
      Sorted := False;
    end;
    FStyle := Value;

    end;
  end;

  { TListBoxStrings }

  function TListBoxStrings.GetCount: Integer;
  begin
    Result := SendMessage(ListBox.Handle, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
  end;
     
  function TListBoxStrings.GetObject(Index: Integer): TObject;
  begin
    if ListBox.Style in [lbVirtual] then
    Result := ListBox.DoGetDataObject(Index)
    else
    begin
      Result := TObject(ListBox.GetItemData(Index));  // Compiler complains here on TObject...
      if Longint(Result) = LB_ERR then Error(SListIndexError, Index);  // ...and here on Longint
    end;
  end;

  procedure TListBoxStrings.PutObject(Index: Integer; AObject: TObject);
  begin
    if (Index <> -1) and not (ListBox.Style in [lbVirtual]) then
    ListBox.SetItemData(Index, LongInt(AObject));
  end;

  end.
```

My Form:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  L_ListBox;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    L_ListBox1: TL_ListBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure L_ListBox1Data(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      var Data: string);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyList : TStringlist;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MyList := TStringlist.Create;
 L_ListBox1.Style := lbVirtual;

 MyList.LoadFromFile('ex.txt');

 L_ListBox1.Count := MyList.Count;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MyList.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.L_ListBox1Data(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  var Data: string);
begin
  Data := MyList[Index];
end;

end.
```

I corrected the code in **L_ListBox.pas**

```
procedure Register;

implementation

uses RTLConsts;

  resourcestring
    SErrorSettingCount = 'Error setting% s.Count';
    SListBoxMustBeVirtual = 'Listbox (% s) style must be virtual in order to set Count';
    SListIndexError = 'List% s is invalid';

  procedure Register;
  begin
  
   RegisterComponents ('ex', [TL_ListBox]);
  end;
```

I am getting an error:

> [Debugger Exception Notification]
> Project project1 raised exception class 'Exception' with message:
> Error setting L_ListBox1.Count

Comment: You say: *I get errors during compilation.* If you had also said what errors, exactly, and on which line, exactly, maybe somebody would be able to help.

Comment: The compiler stops:


```SErrorSettingCount```,

```SListBoxMustBeVirtual```,

```Longint```,

```Result := TObjectct```,

Comment: Please provide details in the question rather than comments

Comment: Tom Brunberg, David Heffernan ok i corrected the post.

Comment: As per [this topic](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=53787.0) the virtual mode is not implemented (yet): Lazarus simply doesn't have this, because its aim is always to support any platform, not just Windows. The poster there looks for the source code but doesn't know that `{$I *.inc}` is where he should look at (the `.inc` files).

Answer (score 0):

What is the construction in Lazarus ?
since the compiler stops I marked bold
**TObject
Longint**

```
Result := TObject(ListBox.GetItemData(Index));
if Longint(Result) = LB_ERR then Error(SListIndexError, Index);
```

Comment: What does this answer try to solve? I don't understand the [Engrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish) formulation of your second sentence at all. If you're talking about the file **l_listbox.pas** then edit your question and insert Pascal comments at that position. Answers are not a chat!